# NGINX CentOS8 Server Block Configuration Issue

Tags: nginx, centos8, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm facing below issue when i need to activate server block from nginx.conf. Can you check it with me please?

---

**sudo systemctl status nginx.service**

● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-21 18:28:13 +03; 11s ago
Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
Process: 8582 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 2609 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

.....internal system[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
**.....internal nginx[8582]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:8085 failed (13: Permission denied)**
....internal system[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
....internal system[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
... Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a port bigger than 1024 with root privilege, but still got this problem, that's may be caused by SELinux. You can disable selinux and test.or give me permission for port.

Check this port, say 8085, in segange port

```
sudo semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
```

If 8085 doesn't exist in the port list, add it into segange port

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t  -p tcp 8085
```

Comment: Actually, I'm not using SELinux config from server.

Comment: conf file when it is configure with 8080 port nginx working btw . When i change port with 8081 or different value nginx isn't working.

Comment: Sometimes your SELinux is disabled, you need to enforcing it first.

Comment: With above semanage config commands problem is solved. I activate semanage from server. Thank you

Comment: could you please accept answer..